# Azure Resource Template Parameters Hell

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-3.0, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

How do I know which parameters to provide and which parameters are overridden in Azure Resources ?

I am getting these errors and losing lots of time figuring out which parameters I need

Should I just start with the parameters in the parameters file and
paste the defaultvalues in templates? ( If so why don't they already
do this?)

Is there a way to read the actual parameters of the running system. As when I used the **Automation Script** part in **azure the values are null**

[image]

> "$schema":
>   "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
>       "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
>       "parameters": {
>           "virtualMachineScaleSets_Services_name": {
>               **"value": null**
>           },

The Error comes when I paste the parameters from the old config

> 14:01:16 - InvalidTemplate: Deployment template validation failed:
>   'The template parameters 'loadBalancers_LB_xwxservices_MainNode_name,
>   loadBalancers_LB_xwxservices_MainNode_id,
>   loadBalancers_LB_xwxservices_MainNode_id_1, clusters_xwxservices_name,
>   loadBalancers_LB_xwxservices_MainNode_id_5,
>   loadBalancers_LB_xwxservices_MainNode_id_6,
>   loadBalancers_LB_xwxservices_MainNode_id_7,
>   virtualMachineScaleSets_MainNode_name,
>   loadBalancers_LB_xwxservices_MainNode_id_2,
>   loadBalancers_LB_xwxservices_MainNode_id_3,
>   loadBalancers_LB_xwxservices_MainNode_id_4' in the parameters file are
>   not valid;
>
> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 12:27:25 PM - Error:
>   Code=InvalidTemplate;  Message=Deployment template validation failed:
>   'The template parameters  'nt1applicationStartPort,
>   nt2applicationEndPort, nt0ephemeralEndPort, clusterName, 
>   nt2ephemeralEndPort, nt2InstanceCount, nt0applicationStartPort, 
>   nt1fabricHttpGatewayPort, virtualNetworkName, certificateThumbprint, 
>   nt0fabricHttpGatewayPort, nt1InstanceCount, adminUserName, 
>   applicationDiagnosticsStorageAccountName, nt1ephemeralEndPort,
>   vmNodeType0Size,  nt1applicationEndPort, dnsTAName, lbTAIPName,
>   nt0fabricTcpGatewayPort, lbName, dnsName,  adminPassword, nicName,
>   nt2fabricTcpGatewayPort, nt1fabricTcpGatewayPort, 
>   secondaryCertificateUrlValue, vmNodeType2Size, clusterLocation,
>   nt1ephemeralStartPort,  supportLogStorageAccountName,
>   nt2applicationStartPort, sourceVaultValue,  nt0ephemeralStartPort,
>   vmStorageAccountName, nt0applicationEndPort, publicIPAddressName, 
>   computeLocation, nt2fabricHttpGatewayPort, nt2ephemeralStartPort,
>   vmNodeType1Size,  secondaryCertificateThumbprint, certificateUrlValue,
>   nt0InstanceCount, lbIPName' **in the  parameters file are not valid;
>   they are not present in the original template and can  therefore not
>   be provided at deployment time. The only supported parameters for this
>   template are 'virtualMachineScaleSets_Services_name,** 
>   virtualMachineScaleSets_Stateful_name,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to relax.

Autogenerated arm templates aren't meant to be production ready, they need refinement. that is expected. Azure cannot infer any single parameter value instead of you. Usually most of the parameters are populated, but sometimes - not. Nothing you can do about it, fill them out manually.

Comment: I got like more than 300 parameters. They change all the time. Wrote a console app that does that. (:

Comment: you should probably refine the entire template, 300 parameters is beyond nuts

Comment: It is a big deployment schema. They had used lots of resources in Azure. So many configurations. That was the reason I wrote the app. I also want parameters to be in sync with code base. If I can write an addon for slack. I would also like to inform the devops team for infrachanges.

Comment: When we delete the parameters we are able to use the default values. Still you are right we need to make sure the default values still do not conflict with existing resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am staying calm (: . started this question to figure out a way to solve the problem in smaller steps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884446/how-can-i-divide-an-existing-template-into-linked-templates

Comment: Arm templating is still terrible, 2 years later.

Comment: shrug ;) its a lot better now :)