# How can I divide an existing template into linked Templates

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

Auto generated arm templates aren't meant to be production ready, they need refinement. that is expected.

**How can a Devops staff divide auto generated ARM templates into Linked templates?**

**References**

**Linked Templates**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates

**Azure ARM template deployment**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview#template-deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can a Devops staff divide auto generated ARM templates into Linked templates?

Per my understanding, you could leverage [Azure Resource Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy) deployment project through visual studio for a simple to divide your ARM template into Linked templates manually.

After you created the deployment project, you could right click your deployment project and click "Add > New Item", choose "Azure Resource Manager Deployment Template", then copy/paste your existed ARM template into your `azuredeploy.json`, then you could enable **JSON Outline window** by clicking "View > Other Windows > JSON Outline", then you could choose the resources which would be divided into Linked template, then copy the related resource configurations (resource definition, variables, parameters,etc.) into a new "Azure Resource Manager Deployment Template". Here I divided the HostingPlan into a Linked template, when deploying my azure website, I would use the hosting plan linked template as follows:

[image]

[image]

**Deploying azure website with a host plan linked template**

[image]

Azure website deployment template: https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/arm-templates/websitewithlinkedtemplate.json

Then, check the latest deployment log under "SETTING > Deployments" section of your resource group as follows:

[image]

Comment: is it wise to have a top level template which references\links to all sorts of deployment layers such as web\middletier\db.